# How to gather similar lists in a list in r?

Tags: r

I have a list which contains months complexly. And I want to gather same months in a list. January elements in a list, february elements in a list etc...

Here is my data;

```
$`01-2011`
        date   V1
1 01-01-2011 1.48
2 01-02-2011 2.53

$`01-2012`
          date   V1
366 01-01-2012 0.14
367 01-02-2012 1.18

$`02-2015`
           date    V1
1493 02-01-2015 10.06
1494 02-02-2015  0.51

$`02-2016`
           date   V1
1858 02-01-2016 0.00
1859 02-02-2016 2.28
```

And data structure;

```
mix<-list(`01-2011` = structure(list(date = c("01-01-2011", "01-02-2011"
), V1 = c(1.48, 2.53)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    `01-2012` = structure(list(date = c("01-01-2012", "01-02-2012"
    ), V1 = c(0.14, 1.18)), row.names = 366:367, class = "data.frame"), 
    `02-2015` = structure(list(date = c("02-01-2015", "02-02-2015"
    ), V1 = c(10.06, 0.51)), row.names = 1493:1494, class = "data.frame"), 
    `02-2016` = structure(list(date = c("02-01-2016", "02-02-2016"
    ), V1 = c(0, 2.28)), row.names = 1858:1859, class = "data.frame"))
```

Desired output;

```
$jan
$jan$`01-2011`
        date   V1
1 01-01-2011 1.48
2 01-02-2011 2.53

$jan$`01-2012`
          date   V1
366 01-01-2012 0.14
367 01-02-2012 1.18


$feb
$feb$`02-2015`
           date    V1
1493 02-01-2015 10.06
1494 02-02-2015  0.51

$feb$`02-2016`
           date   V1
1858 02-01-2016 0.00
1859 02-02-2016 2.28
```

Desired output structure;

```
out<-list(jan = list(`01-2011` = structure(list(date = c("01-01-2011", 
"01-02-2011"), V1 = c(1.48, 2.53)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    `01-2012` = structure(list(date = c("01-01-2012", "01-02-2012"
    ), V1 = c(0.14, 1.18)), row.names = 366:367, class = "data.frame")), 
    feb = list(`02-2015` = structure(list(date = c("02-01-2015", 
    "02-02-2015"), V1 = c(10.06, 0.51)), row.names = 1493:1494, class = "data.frame"), 
        `02-2016` = structure(list(date = c("02-01-2016", "02-02-2016"
        ), V1 = c(0, 2.28)), row.names = 1858:1859, class = "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `split` :

```
split(mix, month.abb[as.integer(sub('-.*', '', names(mix)))])

#$Feb
#$Feb$`02-2015`
#           date    V1
#1493 02-01-2015 10.06
#1494 02-02-2015  0.51

#$Feb$`02-2016`
#           date   V1
#1858 02-01-2016 0.00
#1859 02-02-2016 2.28


#$Jan
#$Jan$`01-2011`
#        date   V1
#1 01-01-2011 1.48
#2 01-02-2011 2.53

#$Jan$`01-2012`
#          date   V1
#366 01-01-2012 0.14
#367 01-02-2012 1.18
```

Using `sub` we extract only month part from the names of the list (01, 02). We convert it into integer use `month.abb` to get corresponding name of the month and put in `split` to get months together.

Answer (score 0):

We could convert the `names` to `yearmon` from `zoo` and then do the `split` by getting the `substr`ing of first 3 characters

```
library(zoo)
split(mix, substr(as.yearmon(names(mix), '%m-%Y'), 1, 3))
#$Feb
#$Feb$`02-2015`
#           date    V1
#1493 02-01-2015 10.06
#1494 02-02-2015  0.51

#$Feb$`02-2016`
#           date   V1
#1858 02-01-2016 0.00
#1859 02-02-2016 2.28


#$Jan
#$Jan$`01-2011`
#        date   V1
#1 01-01-2011 1.48
#2 01-02-2011 2.53

#$Jan$`01-2012`
#          date   V1
#366 01-01-2012 0.14
#367 01-02-2012 1.18
```

Answer (score 0):

$jan
$jan$`01-2011`
        date   V1
1 01-01-2011 1.48
2 01-02-2011 2.53

$jan$`01-2012`
          date   V1
366 01-01-2012 0.14
367 01-02-2012 1.18

$feb
$feb$`02-2015`
           date    V1
1493 02-01-2015 10.06
1494 02-02-2015  0.51

$feb$`02-2016`
           date   V1
1858 02-01-2016 0.00
1859 02-02-2016 2.28

Comment: Hello Benyahdou. Please include the code you wrote to generate the answer, so the person who asked the question can see how you answered it.